# Не могу сохранить данные о погоде если использую кнопки в Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

У меня такая проблема, если я перехожу по кнопкам в Navigation и захожу обратно в MainActivity, то моя погода не сохраняется. И еще странный баг, тоже когда перехожу по фрагментам у меня перестает работать кнопка поиска при поиске погоды, не знаю почему при первом запуске работает хорошо. Заранее спасибо!

```
package com.ggenius.wtw

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_today.*
import org.json.JSONObject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    private lateinit var btnSearch: ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        //Получение координат
        val lat=intent.getStringExtra("lat")
        var long=intent.getStringExtra("long")

        getJsonData(lat,long)

        //Кнопка поиска
        btnSearch=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnSearch)
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val city = etCityName.text.toString()
            if (city.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Введите город",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                loadWeatherByCityName(city)
            }
        }

        //Навигатор
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.todayFragment, R.id.sevenDaysFragment, R.id.settingsFragment))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
    //Загрузка по кнопке
    private fun loadWeatherByCityName(city: String) {
        val API_KEY = "02a131db06297a28f7490797aea8925e"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric&lang=ru"
        val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                setValues(response)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { Toast.makeText(this,"Неверное имя",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
        queue.add(jsonRequest)
    }

    //Загрузка по локации
    private fun getJsonData(lat:String?,long:String?) {
        val API_KEY = "02a131db06297a28f7490797aea8925e"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric&lang=ru"
        val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            Response.Listener { response ->

                setValues(response)

            },
            Response.ErrorListener { Toast.makeText(this,"Неверное имя",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
        queue.add(jsonRequest)
    }

    //Получение данных из api
    private fun setValues(response: JSONObject) {
        city.text=response.getString("name")
        weather.text=response.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description")
        var tempreture=response.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp")
        tempreture=((((tempreture).toFloat())).toInt()).toString()
        temp.text="${tempreture}°C"
        var feels_like_temp = response.getJSONObject("main").getString("feels_like")
        feels_like_temp="Ощущается как "+((((feels_like_temp).toFloat())).toInt()).toString()
        feels_like.text=feels_like_temp+"°C"
        var davlenie=response.getJSONObject("main").getString("pressure")
        davlenie=((((davlenie).toFloat())).toInt()*0.75).toString()
        pressure.text="${davlenie} мм рт ст"
        humidity.text=response.getJSONObject("main").getString("humidity")+"%"
        wind.text=response.getJSONObject("wind").getString("speed")+" м/с"

        val imageCode = response.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getInt("id")

        var imageName = "03d"


        val clearSky = "01d"
        val clearSkyNight = "01n"
        val fewClouds = "02d"
        val fewCloudsNight = "02n"
        val scatteredClouds = "03d"
        val scatteredCloudsNight = "03n"
        val brokenClouds = "04d"
        val brokenCloudsNight = "04n"
        val showerRain = "09d"
        val showerRainNight = "09n"
        val rain = "10d"
        val rainNight = "10n"
        val thunderstorm = "11d"
        val thunderstormNight = "11n"
        val snow = "13d"
        val snowNight = "13n"
        val mist = "50d"
        val mistNight = "50n"

        if (imageCode in 0..300){
            imageName = thunderstorm
        }
        else if (imageCode in 300..500){
            imageName = showerRain
        }
        else if (imageCode in 500..510){
            imageName = rain
        }
        else if (imageCode == 511) {
            imageName = snow
        }
        else if (imageCode in 512..600) {
            imageName = showerRain
        }
        else if (imageCode in 600..700){
            imageName = snow
        }
        else if (imageCode in 701..781){
            imageName = mist
        }
        else if (imageCode in 782..800){
            imageName = clearSky
        }
        else if (imageCode == 800){
            imageName = clearSky
        }
        else if (imageCode == 801){
            imageName = fewClouds
        }
        else if (imageCode == 802){
            imageName = scatteredClouds
        }
        else if (imageCode == 803 && imageCode == 804){
                imageName = brokenClouds
        }
        else if (imageCode == 903) {
            imageName = snow
        }
        else if (imageCode == 904) {
            imageName = clearSky
        }
        else if (imageCode in 905..1000) {
            imageName = thunderstorm
        }



        imageView = findViewById(R.id.weather_icon)
        Picasso.get()
            .load("https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${imageName}@2x.png")
            .into(imageView)
    }
}
```

[image: Вот фото при старте приложения]

[image: А здесь после того как понажимал по кнопкам]

Comment: Я знаю что это скорее не ответ,а рекомендация, но лично я решил был отказаться от обычного нижнего меню и создать свой. Сначала в макет я добавил своё нижнее меню (используя LinearLayout) и в него нужные мне кнопки (еще один из плюсов это то что неограниченной кол-во кнопок). Затем создал ViewPager2 и в него поместил нужные мне фрагменты. затем установил слушатели для кнопок моего нижнего меню где при нажатии ViewPager перемещался на нужный фрагмент. И ещё из плюсов то что можно листать свайпом.  Только не забудьте указать метод setOffscreenPageLimit() чтобы фрагменты сохраняли свой цикл жизни

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я все ровно по-другому хотел

Comment: Возможно эта статья вам поможет https://blog.mindorks.com/saving-fragment-states-with-bottomnvaigationview. В ней фрагмент не завершает свой цикл жизни а просто скрывается с экрана тем самым остаётся его цикл жизни